# Refresh Json Data in VueJsonCSV component - VueJS

Tags: javascript, json, vue.js, vue-component, nuxt.js

I'm using the VueJsonCSV component to export this data to csv. The values for these are retrieved from Vuex Store.

```html
<template>
  <v-btn depressed> <download-csv :data="json_data"> Export Files </download-csv> </v-btn>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      json_data: [
        {
          No: '1',
          Parameters: 'Scenario Name',
          Values: `${this.$store.state.scenario.scenario}`,
        },
        {
          No: '2',
          Parameters: 'Terrain Name',
          Values: `${this.$store.state.scenario.environment.ground}`,
        },
        {
          No: '3',
          Parameters: 'Frequency',
          Values: `${this.$store.state.scenario.environment['antennas-db'].frequency}`,
        },
        {
          No: '4',
          Parameters: 'Environment_type',
          Values: `${this.$store.state.scenario.environment.network['ground-profile']}`,
        },
        {
          No: '5',
          Parameters: 'Downlink_scheduler_type',
          Values: `${this.$store.state.scenario.environment['antennas-db'].scheduler}`,
        },
      ],
    }
  },
}
</script>
```

On updating these values from Vuex store, these data aren't changing in json_data and exporting the old data. They should be automatically updated and refreshed in this json_data to export to csv but while exporting it is exporting the old data not the updated data from Vuex store. What function should I use in script? **Anyone who knows VueJS please help!**

Comment: This is in `data()` or in `computed()`?

Comment: Use a Vuex getter to generate the data and then simply grab the output.

Comment: So, `json_data` is used somewhere in a `computed()`?

Comment: It is in data() { return{

Comment: Yeah I'm printing the values of store they are being updated and printing correctly, but here in json data, those are being updated and while exporting to csv its exporting the old data.

Comment: `data()` is static, it will not be reactive if the values are updated. Try it in a `computed()`.

Comment: Do I create a separate function? It would be of great help if You sent the code. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This kind of code should be totally reactive

```html
<template>
  <button>
    <pre>{{ jsonData }}</pre>
  </button>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  computed: {
    jsonData() {
      return [
        {
          No: '1',
          Parameters: 'Scenario Name',
          Values: `${this.$store.state.scenario.scenario}`,
        },
        {
          No: '2',
          Parameters: 'Terrain Name',
          Values: `${this.$store.state.scenario.environment.ground}`,
        },
        {
          No: '3',
          Parameters: 'Frequency',
          Values: `${this.$store.state.scenario.environment['antennas-db'].frequency}`,
        },
        {
          No: '4',
          Parameters: 'Environment_type',
          Values: `${this.$store.state.scenario.environment.network['ground-profile']}`,
        },
        {
          No: '5',
          Parameters: 'Downlink_scheduler_type',
          Values: `${this.$store.state.scenario.environment['antennas-db'].scheduler}`,
        },
      ]
    },
  },
}
</script>
```

`data()` is not really meant to be reactive, while `computed()` is.